# Pass url to a bash script for use in scp

Tags: bash, ssh, scp

I'm writing a cron to backup some stuffs on a server.
Basically I'm sending specific files form a local directory using scp.
I'm using a public key to avoid authentication.

For reusability I'm passing the local directory and the server url by arguments to my bash script.

How I set my parameters:

```
#!/bin/bash

DIR="$1"
URL="$2"
FILES="$DIR*.ext"
```

My problem is about formatting the url.

### Without formatting

How I send files to the server:

```
#!/bin/bash

for F in $FILEs
do
    scp $F $URL;

    if ssh $URL stat $(basename "$F")
    then
        rm $F
    else 
        echo "Fails to copy $F to $URL"
    fi
done
```

If I try to copy at user's home on the server I do:

```
$ ~/backup /path/to/local/folder/ user@server.com:
```

If I try to copy at a specific directory on the server I do:

```
$ ~/backup /path/to/local/folder/ user@server.com:/path/to/remote/folder/
```

In all cases it gives me the well known error (and my custom echo):

```
ssh: Could not resolve hostname user@server.com: nodename nor [...]
Can't upload /path/to/local/folder/file.ext to user@server.com
```

And it works anyway (the file is copied). But that's not a solution, cause as scp fails (seems to), the file is never deleted.

### With formatting

I tried sending files using this method:

```
#!/bin/bash

for F in $FILES
do
    scp $F "$URL:"
done
```

I no longer get an error, and it works for copying at user's home directory then deleting the local file:

```
$ ~/backup /path/to/local/folder/ user@server.com
```

But, of course, sending to a specific directory don't work at all.

### Finally

So I think that my first method is more appropriate, but how can I get rid of that error?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Your mistake is that you can `scp` to `user@server.com:` but not `ssh` to it : you need to remove the trailing `:` character (and possible path after it). You can do it easily like this with `bash` *parameter expansion* :

```
ssh "${URL%:*}" stat "$(basename "$F")"
```

**RECOMMENDATIONS**

- "USE MORE QUOTES!" They are vital. Also, learn the difference between ' and " and `. See http://mywiki.wooledge.org/Quotes and http://wiki.bash-hackers.org/syntax/words
- if you have spaces in filenames, your code will breaks things up. Better use `while IFS= read -r line; do #stuff with $line; done < file.txt`
- See [bash parameter expansion](http://wiki.bash-hackers.org/syntax/pe)

Comment: Thanks for the documentation!
You're right, the error comes from the `ssh stat`. And I realized that if I want to do a `ssh stat` on a specific remote directory I have to use the syntax `ssh user@server.com stat /path/to/remote/directory/`. As my goal was to be able to catch basic url "user@server.com" and specific directory "user@server.com:/remote/path" I can't do that without test, and string manipulations, so I will pass the server url and the path separately.